# I have a problem with OneDrive when trying to use VBA to access files in the OneDrive folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have a OneDrive Excel workbook which I have open on my local PC. I have a macro which produces an invoice and saves it in pdf format to a sub-directory on my OneDrive. No problem so far. However, when I use another macro to attach the previously saved file, the macro cannot find the file. I have established the sub-directory exists using

```
Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean
    Dim Request As Object
    Dim ff As Integer
    Dim rc As Variant

    On Error GoTo EndNow
    Set Request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    With Request
      .Open "GET", url, False
      .Send
      rc = .StatusText
    End With
    Set Request = Nothing
    If rc = "OK" Then URLExists = True

    Exit Function
EndNow:
End Function
```

but using

```
Function FileExists(filename)
    On Error Resume Next
    FileExists = (Dir(filename) <> "")
End Function
```

gives me a file not found error

This is the full 'SendEmail' sub that I am using.

```
Sub SendMail()
    Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1                        '*** Send message using the local SMTP service pickup directory.
    Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2                          '*** Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).
    Const cdoAnonymous = 0                              '*** Do not authenticate
    Const cdoBasic = 1                                  '*** Basic (clear-text) authentication
    Const cdoNTLM = 2                                   '*** NTLM
    mySubject = Trim(Cells(16, 3))
    myTestEmail = Trim(Cells(12, 12))
    myAttachment1 = myFileName & ".pdf"
    myAttachment1 = "Testing.xlsx"
    '*******************************************
    '*** This bit checks the pdf file exists ***
    '*******************************************
    If Not FileExists(myProgramPath & myAttachment1) Then '--- This gives TRUE i.e. file does not exist
        MsgBox "Attachment file does not exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    '--- This is the format of the url "https://d.docs.live.net/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxx/"
    '--- I've tried changing the direction of the "/" with myProgramPath = Replace(myProgramPath, "\", "/")
    '--- but makes no difference which way they face

    If Not URLExists(myProgramPath) Then '--- This is FALSE i.e. folder does exist
        MsgBox "Folder does not exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    Set objConf = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
    objMessage.AddAttachment myProgramPath & myAttachment1 '--- This is where the error occurs
    objMessage.CreateMHTMLBody "file://" & myProgramPath & "StatementBody.html" '*** This is the html file that creates the body of the email
    myTo = Trim(Cells(22, 5))
    myFrom = Chr(34) & "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" & Chr(34) & "<" & "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxx" & ">"
    myFrom = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx <" & "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxx" & ">"
    myBcc = Trim(Sheets("Lookups & Validation").Cells(13, 9))
    objMessage.Subject = mySubject
    objMessage.From = myFrom
    objMessage.To = myTo
    objMessage.bcc = myBcc
    '*** This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.ionos.co.uk"                     '*** Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoBasic                         '*** Type of authentication, NONE, Basic (Base64 encoded), NTLM
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "xxxxx@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"              '*** Your UserID on the SMTP server
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "Dulceetdec0rumest%"                 '*** Your password on the SMTP server
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587                                      '*** Server port (typically 25)
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False                                       '*** Use SSL for the connection (False or True)
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60                               '*** Connection Timeout in seconds (the maximum time CDO will try to establish a connection to the SMTP server)
    objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
    '*** End remote SMTP server configuration section
    objMessage.Send
    Set objMessage = Nothing
    Set objConf = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve]? We need at least to see how you call your functions and which parameters you give as arguments.

Comment: You cannot use Dir() on a HTTP path - it only works on files/folders, not via other protocols like http.

Comment: Not sure if this is where I reply as I'm new to this but here's the 'SendEmail' sub that I am using.

Comment: @Jimbo if you want to add more information to your question please use the [edit] button.

Comment: `myFileName` is not defined in this sub it is a global variable if yes please show its declaration and check its value. Note that you override your variable  `myAttachment1 = "Testing.xlsx"` also the variable `myProgramPath` is not declared here. Make sure you use `Option Explicit`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to:

1. launch OneDrive
2. create a separate folder for your Excel workbook
   with macro
3. right click the folder it and select "Always keep on this
   device"

That way your vba code should refer to local files and not refer to it's cloud location

Comment: This solution is not working for me.